How can I enable openMP in Mac OS for mgcv R package?
I'm trying to run GAMMs in mgcv and hoping to utilise multi-threaded computation but openMP is not enabled on my Apple M2 Pro running Sonoma 14.1.1. I don't know a lot about the back-end of R, so appreciate simple explanations if possible!
I've installed libomp via homebrew and my Makevars file is set up as follows:
FLIBS   =-L/opt/homebrew/opt/gfortran/lib
F77     = /opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
FC      = /opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran

CFLAGS   = -I/opt/homebrew/include
CPPFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/include
CXXFLAGS = -I/opt/homebrew/include

LDFLAGS += -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib -lomp
CPPFLAGS += -Xclang -fopenmp

I've also tried -Xpreprocessor in CPPFLAGS and get the same result.
When I install mgcv from source I get fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found. I think this means that the path to libomp isn't quite right but I'm not sure how to fix it. Full output below:
> install.packages("mgcv", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mgcv_1.9-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1083217 bytes (1.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mgcv’ ...
** package ‘mgcv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX14.2.sdk’
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/homebrew/include -Xclang -fopenmp    -fPIC  -I/opt/homebrew/include -c coxph.c -o coxph.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/homebrew/include -Xclang -fopenmp    -fPIC  -I/opt/homebrew/include -c davies.c -o davies.o
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/homebrew/include -Xclang -fopenmp    -fPIC  -I/opt/homebrew/include -c discrete.c -o discrete.o
discrete.c:26:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [discrete.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mgcv’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/mgcv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mgcv’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/lm/67l59t7s7qb61nx7mc1b6lsh0000gn/T/Rtmp0qj8PW/downloaded_packages’


You may check this answer and its associated comments, to find where omp.h is located.

See this page https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/ for a discussion.  In summary, Apple doesn't enable OpenMP in the compilers it uses, but there are experimental ways to use it anyway.  From other pages on that site:  generally Homebrew builds are not compatible with CRAN builds.  If you want to use Homebrew OpenMP, you need to build all of R and all packages using Homebrew tools and libs.

Thanks both!
I didn't realise that I needed to build R with Homebrew to use Homebrew OpenMP. I've just uninstalled and reinstalled R and R Studio (without Homebrew) and the mac r-project approach seems to be working now. I had tried it before and it didn't work and I'm not sure what I've done that fixed it but relieved it's working.
@PierU Sorry to clarify, I did know where omp.h was located (opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/include) but didn't know which part of the Makevars file I needed to edit or how to tell R that.

Having just done this myself, I mostly followed the instructions on https://mac.r-project.org/openmp/ as per @user2554330's comment.
I personally wanted to control OpenMP being used or not, so I didn't want to add the relevant flags to ~/.R/Makevars, instead I wanted to choose what gets OpenMP support given the warning about this all being very experimental.
Note: I am using R Core's build of R (installed via brew install --cask r) so that for most things I can use the binary builds of packages provided by R Core.
Follow the instructions on the R Mac OpenMP page to download the version of OpenMP for your OS/clang. To check, you can run
clang -v

to have it print out what version of clang you are using.
Then follow these steps:

Download a copy of the mgcv tarball and unpack it to your disk. Alternatively, if you use git, clone the readonly repo from the CRAN github: https://github.com/cran/mgcv

Find in the mgcv package sources the file src/Makevars and edit it so it reads:
PKG_LIBS =  $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)

PKG_LIBS += -lomp
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -Xclang -fopenmp

Note that the last two lines above are the lines I added to Makevars to enable OpenMP support, and the rest of the file is just comment.

cd to the build directory/folder (i.e. where you want to build the pkg tarball - this can be any location on your system),

Run R CMD build --no-build-vignettes path/to/source

In the build directory run R CMD INSTALL mgcv_1.9-1.tar.gz

Start a new R session

Load mgcv with library("mgcv")

Run the unexported function mgcv:::mgcv.omp()

If that returns TRUE you are golden. If it doesn't, go back and check previous steps.

As a final step that I tried just to confirm things work, I ran mgcv::blas.thread.test(n = 10000) to force something in mgcv to run threaded coded.

Enjoy your model fitting with OpenMP.


I used the git clone option because I want to be able to update the package sources each time there is a release of mgcv and not have to remember what I did to enable OpenMP each time.

Thank you Gavin! I had tried the mac r-project instructions previously and they hadn't worked but after reinstalling R and R Studio it seems they are. However, as you say, it would be better to not use an experimental approach universally. A couple of questions (apologies if they have obvious answers):

Where is the src/Makevars file? I can't find an src folder on my disk (even with hidden files on)
Would the directory/folder that I want to build mgcv in be the output of .libPaths()? For my computer: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library


src/Makefile is in the mgcv tarball you download and unpacked. You edit this file so it only affects the compilation of this package. The build directory is just some other location on your system; when you run R CMD INSTALL bit it will take the built package (the .tar.gz) and install it to your library location. You just don't want to build the package in the folder where the package sources are.
